# Loosing session every time I make a code change with express js app

Tags: node.js, express, session

I've only been working with express and react for a little while. The first app I worked was set up pretty well. The new one I am on is set up well too, but there is a little problem with session when I make a code change.

When I make a change to the code, save, and look at the app, I need to re-login EVERY TIME.

I've looked at a bunch of blogs and SO posts, and most seem to be trying to solve session problems in a prod environment with stores like Redis, etc.

It would seem to me, that express-session should be suitable to do this in a development environment. No?

This is what index.js looks like:

```
/*
    Configure the Google strategy used by Passport.

    OAuth 2.0-based strategies require a `verify` function which receives the
    credential (`accessToken`) for accessing the Google API on the user's
    behalf, along with the user's profile.  The function must invoke `callback`
    with a user object, which will be set at `req.user` in route handlers after
    authentication. ie. callback(err, user)
*/

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: `${process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID}`,
        clientSecret: `${process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}`,
        callbackURL: `${process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK_URL}`
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, idToken, profile, callback) => {
        const onSuccess = (res) => {
            /*
                res.data = {
                    refresh_jwt: refresh token,
                    api_jwt: access token
                }
             */
            callback(null, res.data);
        }
        const onError = (err) => {
            callback(new Error('Google OAuth Failed'), null);
        }
        getOauthData('google', idToken.id_token, onSuccess, onError);
    })
);

/*
    Configure Passport authenticated session persistence.

    In order to restore authentication state across HTTP requests, Passport needs
    to serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.
*/

passport.serializeUser((user, callback) => {
    const sessionUser = {
        refresh_jwt: user.refresh_jwt,
        api_jwt: user.api_jwt
    };
    callback(null, sessionUser);
});
passport.deserializeUser((sessionUser, callback) => {
    verifyIdentity(sessionUser.api_jwt, sessionUser.refresh_jwt, callback);
});

/* Start app */

var app = express();
app.disable('x-powered-by');

/* -- Application-level middleware -- */

/* Configure session */

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
var sess = {
    secret: `${process.env.COOKIE_IDENT_SECRET}`,
    name: "ident",
    proxy: true,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        expires: 604800000, // 1 week
        secure: true
    }
}
app.use(session(sess));

/* Initialize Passport and restore authentication state, if any, from the session. */

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: You're using secure: true on your cookie. Are you serving this over https? Cause if not, no cookie is actually set in your browser.

Comment: Not in development, but yes in production.

Comment: Well then that's your answer. Check in your browser's dev tools, and you'll see there's no cookie, so ofc you need to log in again every time. The simple fix is to do an ENV check. `if(process.ENV.NODE_ENV !== 'production) sess.cookie.secure = false`

Comment: hmm, I set it false just to see if it would work but I'm still experiencing the same problem. Is there another possible problem in addition to that?

Comment: I'm unsure. Does it keep logged in during the same server session - meaning if you log in after server restart, then log out / destroy cookie, then log in again and refresh the page, does it remember your logged in state?

Comment: Yes, when when the server restarts and forces me to re-login I end up back at the page I was originally on.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html)

> Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, just the session ID. Session data is stored server-side.
>
> The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore

So everytime you restart app, the memory is going to be wiped along with sessions stored. If you need persistent `session`, store it in some persistent store, `db` etc, using one of the `Session Stores` available under **Compatible Session Stores** in the same link.

An example from `connect-mongo` using `mongodb` as persistent storage:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore(options)
}));
```